# javax.xml.ws.Service could not read wsdlDocumentationLocation which is declare as URL('file:Authentication.wsdl')

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, wsdl

My Java servlet, developed with JDeveloper 11g R2 and deployed on a WebLogic Server 10.3.6, needs to communicate with a specific WebService developed by a tiers company.

The `javax.xml.ws.Service` is created with `wsdlDocumentLocation` as a URL (`'file:Authentication.wsdl'`).

Everything works fine on my server where the FireWall is disabled.

But on the customer server, I get the following error:

```
file:Authentication.wsdl 
Jan 22, 2016 9:27:32 AM weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider createServiceDelegate WARNING: Could not read WSDL Definition from URL wsdlDocumentLocation: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException. 
Jan 22, 2016 9:27:32 AM weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate addWsdlDefinitionFeature SEVERE: Failed to create WsdlDefinitionFeature for wsdl location: file:Authentication.wsdl, error: com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException, message: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.
```

I suspect the firewall on the customer server to block the access to the file `Authentication.wsdl`?

I'm not sure but, for what I understand, using a URL with `file:` point to a local file accessed by some network protocol? Am I right?

If it's true, can you explain me what type of rules I should set in my firewall (Linux) to give access to this local file?

Does `file:Authentication.wsdl` means http://localhost:Authentication.wsdl or something like http://localhost/myServletContext/Authentication.wsdl?

I can not figure out what I need to do to solve this issue.

I did futher tests and display informations about the URL objet. For new URL('file:/tmp/Authentication.wsdl'), getPort() returns -1, getHost() returns nothing and getPath() returns /tmp/Authentication.wsdl.

My Authentication.wsdl is inside my jar file which I use in my war file.

Comment: Is Authentication.wsdl inside your .war file?

Comment: The Authentication.wsdl is inside the jar file whicj is inside my war file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“file:Authentication.wsdl” is not a network protocol.  It just refers to a plain old file name, on the same system.

It fails because your Authentication.wsdl is not actually a file.  It's an entry in a .jar file, which I assume is on the classpath (as all .jar files in a .war file's WEB-INF/lib structure are).  For this reason, a `file:` URL will *never* work in a production environment.  No one distributes Java applications in unarchived form (for a number of good reasons).

An entry which is in the classpath is known as a resource.  The correct way to access such data is with the [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) method, which scans the classpath for the requested entry:

```
URL wsdlLocation = MyServlet.class.getResource("Authentication.wsdl");
```

Note, however, that this will look for Authentication.wsdl in the *same package* as your class.  If your Authentication.wsdl is in the root of your archive, you *could* alter the string argument to find it—but you shouldn't.  Placing resources in the root of an archive is very much like placing files in the root of the C: drive;  it carries a risk of conflict with the multitude of other libraries in the classpath.  That's why Class.getResource assumes, by default, that your file is in a directory that matches the Class object's package structure.

Meaning, if your servlet class is in the `com.example.myapp` package, Authentication.wsdl should be in the .jar file as `com/example/myapp/Authentication.wsdl`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed explanation. It's obviously better to use the getResource method. I'll give it a try.